# OAuth2 Implicit Grant with Ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, oauth

I'm implementing OAuth's implicit grant type in a Javascript application using Angular.  I would like to request a token using an AJAX request.  When I make the request to my OAuth server, it responds with a `302` and a `location` header. As per the spec, the location is my configured redirect URL with a hash fragment containing the access token.

My problem is I have no way to read the hash fragments if it is an ajax request, since `XmlHttpRequest` automatically follows the location header.  I can't seem to get any information about the initial response (the one whose status is `302`, and has the location header.)  If there were some way to intercept that response and read out the location header, I would be set.

I would like requesting a token to happen behind the scenes, without the user knowing it is even happening. (That is, without the browser's URL jumping all around.)  I should also mention that I am working within an environment where SSO is available, and the user will most likely have already authenticated via SSO. As long as my OAuth server detects an SSO cookie, it will know the user has been previously authenticated and to just issue a token for this application, without needing to redirect to a login page.

Is there any way to read either the location header of the first response, or to read the URL that is redirected to?  It seems that xhr itself goes to great lengths to prevent this, so I'm also wondering what is the reason for that?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're asking an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

oauth Implicit Grant usually opens the service login window so the user can accept the service integrator then provide their login credentials.  Using JavaScript you can read the hash by implementing code similar to:

```
var browserRef = window.open(add your URL here, '_blank','location=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes');
browserRef.addEventListener ('loadstart', function(event) { add code to read the hash)}
```